# how to refer and see env var in shell if the var name is long and has spaces? how to use echo on it?

Tags: bash, shell, intellij-idea, echo

my env var is IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. using win10 + gitbash.

```
IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\bin
```

How to do echo? This is not working:

```
>echo $IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
>echo ($IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition)
>echo $%IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition%
>echo %IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition%
>echo '$%IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition%'

>echo 'IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition'
```

Other env vars without spaces like QT_SCALE_FACTOR_ROUNDING_POLICY do work
using

```
echo $QT_SCALE_FACTOR_ROUNDING_POLICY
```

EDIT with help of Charles Duffy:

i used
env | grep IDEA and i did get all the stuff with 'IDEA' including the path that i need:

```
$ env | grep IDEA
IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\bin;
PATH=/c/Users/erjan/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/erjan/bin:/c/Program Files/Eclipse Foundation/jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DTS/Binn:/c/Program Files/PuTTY:/c/Program Files/Calibre2:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/cmd:/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/c/python38/Scripts:/c/python38:/c/Users/erjan/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Program Files/Azure Data Studio/bin:/c/Users/erjan/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Users/erjan/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2/bin:/c/kafka_2.12-2.8.0/bin/windows:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
ORIGINAL_PATH=/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/erjan/bin:/c/Program Files/Eclipse Foundation/jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DTS/Binn:/c/Program Files/PuTTY:/c/Program Files/Calibre2:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/cmd:/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/c/python38/Scripts:/c/python38:/c/Users/erjan/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Program Files/Azure Data Studio/bin:/c/Users/erjan/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Users/erjan/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2/bin:/c/kafka_2.12-2.8.0/bin/windows
```

Comment: You cannot have a shell variable name with a space. It is not a legal name.

Comment: You _can_ have an _environment_ variable name with a space, but it won't be translated to a shell variable.

Comment: (btw, the `%VARNAME%` syntax is a Windowsism, and has no meaning in bash).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes sorry, it s actuall env var in system properties that i want to see in shell

Comment: Ahh. I could tell you how to retrieve that on a Linux system with procfs, but on Windows I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, i m in win 10. using gitbash. how?? damn

Comment: I'd suggest starting by looking at the output of the command `env`.

Comment: "Git Bash" -- more properly called msys bash -- doesn't emulate procfs, so the native-Linux way (which involves parsing `/proc/self/environ`) won't work there.

Comment: ...so, your best bet will be to start with `env | grep IDEA`. If that comes up empty, you may be out of luck.

Comment: hmm it did work, exactly what u typed, but my output is much longer...

Comment: If you [edit] that output (and the command you got it from) into the question, that would be helpful for those of us who don't have a Windows machine handy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, done thx u. i need to filter it now..

Comment: Yup, Make it `env | grep '^IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition='` and you'll be there on the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on Windows and don't have procfs, the easiest way to retrieve the full environment is with `env`.

Note that whether the shell strips environment variables with names that don't match legal shell variable names from the environment (thus also making them unavailable to tools like `env`) is implementation-defined; the POSIX sh standard makes it legal for shells to strip such names, but also legal to leave them in, so whether this works can vary by version.

```
idea=$(env | sed -rne '/^IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition=/ { s/^[^=]+=//p }')
if [[ $idea ]]; then
  echo "Found IntelliJ at: $idea"
else
  echo "Could not find IntelliJ"
fi
```